# The resource cannot be found Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This error comes to me.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Dinner

I searched but there is not suitable answers for me.

1. The spell of my controller is correct. I tried and checked many times.
2. I did not customize my rounting Globle.asax
3. I checked the "Web" tab under my project's properties,  the "SpecificPage is tickled without any contents"

Everything is by default. Anyway here is the default code for rounting. Who knows why?Thanks

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }
```

Here is my Dinner controller

```
namespace NerdDinner.Controllers
{
    public class DinnerController : Controller
    {
        IDinnerRepository _repository;
        public DinnerController()
        {
            _repository = new sqlDinnerRepository();
        }

        public DinnerController(IDinnerRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        //
        // GET: /Dinner/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var dinners = _repository.FindAllDinners();
            return View(dinners);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Dinner/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var dinner = _repository.GetDinner(id);
            return View(dinner);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Dinner/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Dinner/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Dinner dinner)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here
                _repository.AddDinner(dinner);
                _repository.UpdateDinner(dinner);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View(dinner);
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Dinner/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var dinner = _repository.GetDinner(id);
            return View(dinner);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Dinner/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {

            var dinner = _repository.GetDinner(id);
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add update logic here
                UpdateModel(dinner, collection.ToValueProvider());
                _repository.UpdateDinner(dinner);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View(dinner);
            }
        }

        //
        // POST: /Dinner/Delete/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            var db = new dbDataContext();
            var dinner = db.Dinners.SingleOrDefault(x => x.DinnerID == id);
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add delete logic here
                _repository.DeleteDinner(dinner);
                _repository.UpdateDinner(dinner);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View(dinner);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is IDinnerRepository interface

```
namespace NerdDinner.Models
{
    interface IDinnerRepository
    {
        IQueryable<Dinner> FindAllDinners();
        Dinner GetDinner(int id);
        void AddDinner(Dinner dinner);
        void UpdateDinner(Dinner dinner);
        void DeleteDinner(Dinner dinner);
    }
}
```

sqlDinnerRepository class implements IDinnerRepository interface

```
namespace NerdDinner.Models
{
    public class sqlDinnerRepository
    {
        dbDataContext db;
        public sqlDinnerRepository()
        {
            db = new dbDataContext();
        }

        public IQueryable<Dinner> FindAllDinners()
        {
            return db.Dinners;
        }

        public Dinner GetDinner(int id)
        {
            return db.Dinners.SingleOrDefault(x => x.DinnerID == id);
        }

        public void AddDinner(Dinner dinner)
        {
            db.Dinners.InsertOnSubmit(dinner);
        }

        public void UpdateDinner(Dinner dinner)
        {
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }

        public void DeleteDinner(Dinner dinner)
        {
            db.Dinners.DeleteOnSubmit(dinner);
        }
    }
}
```

I type `"http://localhost:52372/Dinner"` in my browser.

Comment: please share the code of  Dinner controller and also the complete URL you are writing in browser.

Comment: I put my code there. But I think my code is correct. Because it was working yesterady. I just updated some components like jQuery, Entityframe work,etc. Then this error comes.

Comment: code seems correct.  Have you debugged the code ? add a breakpoint on DinnerController's constructor and try to debug. It might be problem while calling constructor.

Comment: I tried to add a breakpoint on Dinner construtor. It seems not the controller' problem. I got the same error. The project didnt break, it passed the dinner controller.Is it something caused by IIS?I am not sure.